# TSQL RIGHT String function not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, varchar

I am having trouble understanding why the RIGHT function is not working for me. I tried to fit as much output in here, my apologies if it is confusing to read.

```
DECLARE @Nbr VARCHAR(27)

SELECT @Nbr = xmz.nbr
FROM @xml_temp AS xmz

SELECT @Nbr AS 'Number', 
       LEFT(@Nbr, 4) AS 'LEFT', 
       LEN(@Nbr) AS 'Length', 
       SUBSTRING(@Nbr, 10, 4) AS 'SUBSTRING', 
       RIGHT(@Nbr, 4) AS 'RIGHT'
```

Number: 154448887859999 
LEFT: 1544
Length: 15
SUBSTRING: 9999
RIGHT: **EMPTY**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

spaces perhaps,   LEN doesn't count spaces while DATALENGTH does

can you run

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(@Nbr) AS 'Length',
 RIGHT(RTRIM(@Nbr), 4) AS 'RIGHT'
```

Comment: wow that worked, however I don't understand how there would be a space in @Nbr

Comment: The spaces are in the table, `rtrim` when pulling into the variable or `rtrim` before applying the `right` function

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT @Nbr AS 'Number', 
       LEFT(@Nbr, 4) AS 'LEFT', 
       LEN(@Nbr) AS 'Length', 
       SUBSTRING(@Nbr, 10, 4) AS 'SUBSTRING', 
       RIGHT(RTRIM(@Nbr), 4) AS 'RIGHT'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be quite revealing.

```
DECLARE @from char(4) = '5am';
DECLARE @to varchar(4) = '6am';
DECLARE @not_to_be varchar = '7am';
SET @from = RIGHT('0' + @from,4)
SELECT LEN(@from)
SELECT '''' + @from + ''''
SET @to = RIGHT('0' + @to,4)
SELECT LEN(@to)
SELECT '''' + @to + ''''
SET @not_to_be = RIGHT('0' + @not_to_be,4)
SELECT LEN(@not_to_be)
SELECT '''' + @not_to_be + ''''
```

yields the following output

```
(No column name)
```

1   3

```
(No column name)
```

1   '5am '

```
(No column name)
```

1   4

```
(No column name)
```

1   '06am'

```
(No column name)
```

1   1

```
(No column name)
```

1   '0'

See for [yourself](http://rextester.com/KEZ24175)