# collation conflict SQL Server varchar stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I'm using [REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/JSIYY77251) to write a piece of SQL Server code.

It says it's SQL Server 2014 Express Edition that's being used...

Here's the minimal code to cause the message.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #CONVERT_TIME_TO_24_HR
(
  @TIME_STRING varchar(4)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @AMPM as varchar(2);
  SET @AMPM = RIGHT(@TIME_STRING,2);
  IF @AMPM = 'am'
    SELECT 2
END
GO
```

Here's the error:

```
Error(s), warning(s):
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

If the @TIME_STRING is just declared and not a parameter to the stored procedure I don't have an issue. Since I have no control over the SQL Server instance, how do I work around this?

Here's a [forked version](http://rextester.com/MECSMF46111) when it's not a parameter - no issues

```
DECLARE @TIME_STRING varchar(4);
DECLARE @AMPM as varchar(2);
SET @AMPM = RIGHT(@TIME_STRING,2);
  IF @AMPM = 'am'
    SELECT 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would occur because the collation for the server/database/column has different values (probably the server and the database).  You can fix it by explicitly adding in the collation:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #CONVERT_TIME_TO_24_HR (
  @TIME_STRING varchar(4)
) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @AMPM as varchar(2);
  SET @AMPM = RIGHT(@TIME_STRING,2);
  IF @AMPM = 'am' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ;
  SELECT 2;
END;
```

I admit that this is not a common column.  On your own system, the default collations would probably all match.  I have no idea why the designers of Rextester would have different default collations.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It works a treat. Not very intuitive though. Seems odd yo do it on the IF rather than the declaration. Especially if you have multiple IFs too!

Comment: @JGFMK . . . It is not on the `if`.  It is on the constant.  I figure that making the constant have the same collation as the stored data is more sensible, then the other way around.  But as I think about it, it is weird that a constant would get a different collation from variable declaration.  It is too early where I am for me to think about this too hard.

Comment: Unfortunately whilst it passed the syntax checks, the condition for 'am' or 'pm' would never pass....

Comment: Doh... SQL Server RIGHT is flakey as hell. Hate that command for it's inconsistency https://stackoverflow.com/a/44987409/495157

Comment: SET @ AMPM = RIGHT(@ TIME_STRING,2); gives wrong result
  SET @ AMPM = SUBSTRING(@ TIME_STRING,LEN(@ TIME_STRING)-1,2) works - bad stack overflow doesn't like @ with no space between